# Arduino String cast vs String constructor

Tags: constructor, casting, arduino

My question is what is the overhead of casting a variable, say a primitive type, to an Arduino `String` vs using the `String` constructor.

From my understanding of c# I understand that certain types of casts are set at compile time and have no run time overhead, but implementing a new object with a constructor would.

Would the same be true with the Arduino String library?

Where:

```
uint8_t u = 0x88;
```

Both:

```
auto a = String(u);
auto a = (String)u;
```

seem to create the same String object.
So ignoring the evils of strings for now, which has the least over head?